# IJCADで円弧を作成した際の曲線の開始点・終点を取得する方法について

Tags: c#, .net, ijcad

円弧を作成したあと、ARC(Curve)のStartPointを利用しても開始点ではなく終点が取れることがありますが、
線を引いた際の開始点を取る方法はあるのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
※プログラムから取得した際も同様

```
using (Transaction acTrans = acDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
{
    PromptSelectionResult res = acEdr.GetSelection();
    if (res.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
    {
        foreach (ObjectId objId in res.Value.GetObjectIds())
        {
            using (Entity ent = acTrans.GetObject(objId, OpenMode.ForRead) as Entity)
            {
                if (ent is Arc arc)
                {
                    // 円弧の場合、開始点と終点を取得（逆転している）
                    Point3d startPoint = arc.StartPoint;
                    Point3d endPoint = arc.StartPoint;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 線を引いた際の開始点を取る方法はあるのでしょうか？

円弧(ARC)のプロパティから円弧の線を引いた1点目を取得することはできません。
円弧のAPIの仕様では点をセットした順ではなく、
反時計周り方向を正として始点(Curve.StartPoint)、終点(Curve.EndPoint)がセットされます。

プログラムで対応するなら、

- Document.BeginCommand など、ARCコマンドを監視するイベント
- Editor.PointMonitor など、マウスの座標を監視するイベント
- DBObject.XData など、独自の情報を保持するプロパティ
- Database.ObjectAppended など、Databaseの変更を監視するイベント

といったAPIを組み合わせて、ARCオブジェクトをデータベースに追加する直前に、
ARCオブジェクトの拡張データに最初にクリックした点の座標を保持させて、
ARCオブジェクトの拡張データから最初にクリックした点を取得する
という方法が考えられます。